# Using LockFileEX in C#

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, locking

#### Background

I'm trying to implement block file locking in my C# application.  The built-in [`FileStream.Lock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.lock.aspx) method throws an exception if it is unable to acquire the lock.

The underlying [`LockFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365202%28VS.85%29.aspx) method returns a status code however I'd prefer not to use a spin-lock to wait for the file to be unlocked.

#### Question

Does anyone have any code snippets in C# showing how to properly construct the [OVERLAPPED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684342%28VS.85%29.aspx) structure with a `wait` handle and pass it to [`LockFileEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365203%28VS.85%29.aspx) and wait for the operation to complete?  I am trying to avoid using the Overlapped.Pack methods partially because they're unsafe but mostly because they require an [`IOCompletionCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.iocompletioncallback.aspx) which isn't what I'm trying to achieve.

I have the declarations but the construction & use of the `OverLapped` structure seems to be a little bit more complicated.

**Note**: I know I need to manually pin the overlapped structure until the wait completes. My current code looks like:

```
ManualResetEvent evt = new ManualResetEvent(false);
OVERLAPPED overlapped = new OVERLAPPED();
overlapped.OffsetLow = offsetLow;
overlapped.OffsetHigh = offsetHigh;
overlapped.hEvent = evt.SafeHandle;
GCHandle h = GCHandle.Alloc(overlapped, GCHandleType.Pinned);
int hr = Win32.LockFileEX(_handle, LockFlags.Exclusive, 0, offsetLow, offsetHigh, 
GCHandle.ToIntPtr(h));
if(hr == 0)
{
    int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    if(error = Win32.ERROR_IO_PENDING)
    {
        evt.WaitOne();
    }
    else
    {
        //ohpoo
    }
}
```

#### Resolution

The code that ended up working as I wanted was:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct OVERLAPPED
{
    public uint internalLow;
    public uint internalHigh;
    public uint offsetLow;
    public uint offsetHigh;
    public IntPtr hEvent;
}

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool LockFileEx(SafeFileHandle handle, uint flags, uint reserved, uint countLow, uint countHigh, ref OVERLAPPED overlapped);

private const uint LOCKFILE_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK = 0x00000002;

public static void Lock(FileStream stream, ulong offset, ulong count)
{
    uint countLow = (uint)count;
    uint countHigh = (uint)(count >> 32);

    OVERLAPPED overlapped = new OVERLAPPED()
    { 
        internalLow = 0,
        internalHigh = 0,
        offsetLow = (uint)offset,
        offsetHigh = (uint)(offset >> 32),
        hEvent = IntPtr.Zero,
    };

    if (!LockFileEx(stream.SafeFileHandle, LOCKFILE_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK, 0, countLow,
        countHigh, ref overlapped))
    {
        //TODO: throw an exception
    }
}
```

This code will block until the exclusive lock on the region can be acquired.

Comment: +1: very nice! Almost worked here: with .NET4 I needed to pass OVERLAPPED with ref, otherwise it resulted in a AccesViolationError. I guess Marshalling behavior changed between 3.5 and 4.0. I edited the answer with this and usigned integers "fixes" (it's more correct to have usigned integers everywhere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should be "very close" to a good solution. The only part I really don't like is using reflection to access an mscorlib internal method, but that method does an *excellent* job converting Win32 error codes to an IOException. Since you already have unsafe code for `NativeOverlapped*`, permissions aren't an issue.

It could probably be further improved by creating a `SafeFileLockHandle` or similar to provide a lightweight `IDisposable` object for unlocking the file derived from `CriticalFinalizerObject`.

```
    private const uint LOCKFILE_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK = 0x00000002;
    private static readonly Action WinIOError;

    static Win32Native()
    {
        BindingFlags bindingAttr = BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
        var winIOErrorMethod = typeof(string).Assembly.GetType("System.IO.__Error").GetMethod("WinIOError", bindingAttr, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null);
        WinIOError = (Action)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), winIOErrorMethod);
    }

    public static void LockFile(SafeFileHandle handle, bool exclusive, long offset, long length, Action action)
    {
        if (handle == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("handle");
        if (handle.IsInvalid)
            throw new ArgumentException("An invalid file handle was specified.", "handle");
        if (offset < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("The offset cannot be negative.", "offset");
        if (length < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("The length cannot be negative.", "length");
        if (action == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

        LockFileUnsafe(handle, exclusive, offset, length, action);
    }

    private static unsafe void LockFileUnsafe(SafeFileHandle handle, bool exclusive, long offset, long length, Action action)
    {
        Overlapped overlapped = new Overlapped();
        overlapped.OffsetHigh = (int)(offset >> 32);
        overlapped.OffsetLow = (int)offset;

        IOCompletionCallback callback =
            (errorCode, numBytes, nativeOverlapped) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    action();
                }
                finally
                {
                    Overlapped.Free(nativeOverlapped);
                }
            };

        NativeOverlapped* native = overlapped.Pack(callback, null);
        uint flags = exclusive ? LOCKFILE_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK : 0;
        if (!LockFileEx(handle, flags, 0, (int)length, (int)(length >> 32), native))
        {
            Overlapped.Free(native);
            WinIOError();
        }
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static unsafe extern bool LockFileEx(SafeFileHandle handle, uint flags, uint mustBeZero, int countLow, int countHigh, NativeOverlapped* overlapped);
```

Comment: Do you know if its possible to not use the overlapped.Pack routines?  I'm really trying to avoid unsafe if I possibly can. What I'm really trying to do is get at the wait handle in the overlapped structure and Wait on it.

Comment: You probably don't want to. The Overlapped methods do *a lot* of work for you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163415.aspx

Comment: If they did what I wanted, I'd have a much harder time not using them just because they're unsafe.  The bigger problem is that they dont fundamentally do what I want.  None of the Win32 file locking apis that I can find are blocking.  I am really trying to fudge blocking locks out of non-blocking ones by using waithandles.

Comment: Blocking locks are worthless without a timeout parameter. Also, don't tie up a .NET thread when you can pass the overlapped operation to the Win32 thread pool and get a notification once the asynchronous operation is complete.

Comment: @280Z28 - *"Blocking locks are worthless without a timeout parameter."* So `EnterCriticalSection` is worthless? The C# `lock` statement is worthless?

Comment: @Earwicker: I guess I should revise that to say "Synchronized code must be known to never deadlock. If you can't enforce this through static analysis of your code, you must use a timeout parameter or provide a mechanism on another non-blocked thread to cancel the operation." Asynchronous Windows API calls fall into the latter two.

Answer (score 0):

[Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com) has the answer (and pinvoke.net and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/7217a8d3-d36d-43c9-ad4f-ad638a9ac1de have the declarations)