# Lock file from being changed by no one except me?

Tags: c#, file, winapi

I need to lock my password dictionary file, i want to lock file from being deleted and changed.

How should i do it? In `C# WinApi` or any thing else?

Comment: Why do you care about a dictionary?  Dictionaries are only used to crack passwords.  Does the file actually contain plain-text passwords?  *Never* do that, only store hashes.

Comment: I will explain, i have a security hashed password list, i have a bad memory for these kind of passwords, i keep them safe they are hashed and 3des encrypted 512bit encryption, but i need to keep in file.

Answer (score 2):

While your program is running you can use [`FileStream.Lock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.lock%28VS.71%29.aspx) and [`FileStream.UnLock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.unlock%28VS.71%29.aspx) for locking the file.

Comment: FileStream.Lock locks only range of bytes in a file.

Answer (score 2):

You can open file with **FileShare.None** and keep it as long as you want it to be locked

```
var stream = new FileStream("file.ext",FileMode.Open,
          FileAccess.ReadWrite,FileShare.None);
//file is locked 


stream.Close(); //lock is release.
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h0z48dh.aspx

Answer (score 1):

why don't you set security on your file (allowing only users you want) and in  your code use impersonation. Impersonation will allow your application  to use  user credentials to  access your file

use Impersonator class from url  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User

```
using (new Impersonator("Username", "Domainname", "Password")) 
{ 
  string pwdfile= File.ReadAllText("c:\dictionaryfile.pwd"); 
  Console.WriteLine(pwdfile); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a *WINAPI alternative*, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784195/using-lockfileex-in-c-sharp). It actually addresses problem that could encountered using `FileStream.Lock`.