# Lock a block of a file

Tags: c#, .net

I have a file that is 192k in size, I want to lock the middle of the file.

Ex) I would like to lock 64k-128k of the file with c#. Any idea how I would lock that part of the file?

Comment: This is known as "byte range locking", and can be very valuable.

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to use [LockFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Locks the specified file for exclusive access by the calling process. This function can operate either synchronously or asynchronously and can request either an exclusive or a shared lock.

You're looking for a shared lock.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool LockFileEx(IntPtr hFile, uint dwFlags, uint dwReserved,
   uint nNumberOfBytesToLockLow, uint nNumberOfBytesToLockHigh,
   [In] ref System.Threading.NativeOverlapped lpOverlapped);
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into the [LockFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function in the Windows API. The same page also mentions a `LockFileEx` function. Yay! Have tons of fun mucking around ;)

The pinvoke site has a page on it: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.lockfile

Answer (score 0):

You cant lock parts of a file using `System.IO`. If you have a open handle on the file, the complete file is locked.

You can do this using WinAPI.

### Check out [Using LockFileEX in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784195/using-lockfileex-in-c-sharp)