# Limiting the number of concurrent users for c# program using a lock-file

Tags: c#

I have made a C# program, and i want to limit the number of concurrent users, for licensing reasons.

The program itself (the exe-file) is installed locally, and the datafiles (not a database) is stored on a shared drive on the server.

My idea was to have a lock-file, that each instance of the program would keep a ReadWrite handle to.

And then I would count the open file handles to the lock-file. When the number of handles would reach 5, i would reject more handles, and not allow the program to start,

Something like:

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"f:\blabla\lock.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);

if (filestream.CountFileHandles()>5) return false;
```

But i can't figure out how to count the open files handles to the lock-file.

I don't want to write anything in the lock-file. Just count the handles.

Or maybe I am following a wrong path, and somebody can guide me to a better solution, how to limit the number of concurrent  users.

Comment: do you have the possibility to run a "license manager" on the server? if so, then that'd be a better solution IMHO

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the server. I sell the program, and the buyers install it on their local PC's, and point to a shared drive, which might be a windows server, NAS, or some other share drive.

Comment: I did something (25 years ago in another language), but it was the basically using a byte range lock (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478271/lock-a-block-of-a-file) and tried to lock byte 1, if that fails, try to lock byte 2 etc. I know things have changed in the intervening 25 years, but my biggest issue at that time was that a program crashing or closed down incorrectly (eg power-failure) would not release the lock hence leading to an false count.You might want to test to see how you program copes with that scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is dirty but this might just work......

You make up front as many lock files as you are going to allow concurrent users. So if you allow 10 users then it will be:

f:\blabla\lock0.txt,
f:\blabla\lock1.txt,
.....,
f:\blabla\lock9.txt

To obtain a 'license' the program iterates through all the files, attempting to read each one **in exclusive mode** eg:

```
File.open(f, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None)
```

Keep trying 0..9 until either this succeeds for one of the files (in which case you now have your license) or else you tried them all (in which case you did not get one)

Make it work as well as possible by cleanly closing the file whenever you exit the program.

Ultimately, there are always issues with home rolled license solutions. If it is more than a handful of concurrent users, some kind of server solution would be better, probably one you did not write yourself.

Comment: This is an excellent solution, and very simple. Much better than a shared lock-file. This also handles the situation, when the program crashes on one of the client PC's, or if they loose connection to the server. In that case the lock will simply dissapear. Thank you very much, for your solution..